# How to validate whether the text of web elements matches in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, assert

I have been working on a project where I need to `assert` text of web elements in `Selenium Python`. Below is the example of what I meant:

**Example**

[image]

what I want to `assert` is the value `6.00` of the far-right of the image and the `$6.00` of the bottom-left of the image.

**Example.py**

```
class Example:

    def checkValue(self):
       element 1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'6.00')]")
       element 2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Total Amount: $6.00')]")
```

**Test.py**

```
class Test:

    def test_1:
        np = new Example()
        np.checkValue()
```

I have included the blueprint for the 2 elements. May I know how to include `assert` command in this `example.py` program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either check if both elements may be found with the given price, or you can check whether the given elements have the expected value.

#### Option1

Find elements by price and let selenium raise the exception:

```py
def check_value(self, expected_price):
    elem1_xp = '//tr[@whatever]//td[contains(text(),"%s")]' % expected_price # xpath of the subtotal price element, adjust it
    elem2_xp = '//div[contains(text(), "Total amount: $%s")]' % expected_price # xpath of the total element, adjust it
    element_1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(elem1_xp)
    element_2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(elem2_xp)
```

With this solution, when `element_1` or `element_2` can't be found, an Exception will be raised and you will see which element couldn't be found. You don't need an assert here. If both elements are found, the check is passed.

If you are searching for `6.00` and it is present twice on the screen, you need to be careful to avoid finding the same element twice (or the element and its parent).

#### Option2

Check if the value of the two elements match. The first and most important thing here is to have a precise `xpath` for both elements.

```py
def check_value(self, expected_price):
    elem1_xp = '//tr[@whatever]//td[4]' # precise xpath of the subtotal price element
    elem2_xp = '//div[contains(text(), "Total amount: $")]' # total price element
    element_1_value = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(elem1_xp).text
    element_2_value = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(elem2_xp).text.replace("Total amount: $", "")
    assert element_1_value == element_2_value == expected_price, "Price mismatch! Expected price is %s, subtotal is %s, total price is %s" % (expected_price, element_1_value, element_2_value)
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? That's quite useful. Will try it out and let u know ASAP

Comment: For the 1st one, I get `Python 2.7 does not support 'f' prefix`. How do I resolve that. I'm using PyCharm 2020.3

Comment: 'f-strings' are python3.6+.

Comment: how about if I instantiate it from the test class? the `expected_price` has to be initialised with something right?

Comment: If you add a $6.00 to the cart, for example `item` which has an `item.price` of `6.00`, then the method should be called with `example_class_instance.check_value(item.price)`.